# Program for ceasar cipher breaks at strcpy function returning segmentation fault

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C to explore the cesarean cipher but I always get segmentation fault when I run it. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ceaserEncrypt(char string[1000000],int key);


int main(int *argc,char *argv[])
{

char str[1000000] = "Hi there I am fine";
int key = 20;
char val[1000000];
strcpy(val,ceaserEncrypt(str,key));
printf("%s",val);

return 0;
}




char ceaserEncrypt(char string[1000000],int key)
{

 int len = strlen(string);
 char encryptlis[len];

if(key < 1 || key > 26)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Key provided is invalid");
    exit(-1);
}

 for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
    if(string[i] = ' '){
        encryptlis[i] = ' ';
        continue;
    }
    int charcode = string[i] + key;
    if(charcode > 122)
    {
        encryptlis[i] = (char) (charcode - 25);
    }

    encryptlis[i] = (char) charcode;

 }


return encryptlis;
}
```

```
Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Processor: Intel celeron 
RAM Size: 4Gb
compiler: gcc
```

I know about segmentation fault. But in this program I don't see where I accessed an illegal memory location because I provided ample size for the encrpylis and val array.
By the way I am a newbie to C. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you already.

Comment: Don't you listen to your compiler's warnings? With `gcc`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It identifies four problems, including the ones that ultimately lead to the SIGSEGV

Comment: Your code gives a lot of errors when compiled with `-Wall -Werror` flags. You can follow them to solve your issue. *I don't see where I accessed an illegal memory location* , no you are accessing illegal memory locations.

Comment: Tip: `const char *string` would be a better argument (no other changes needed as a result of that change)

Comment: Putting million character arrays on the stack is just asking for trouble. Typical stack sizes nowadays are only a few megabytes. In your sample code, there's no reason for `str` or `val` to be a million bytes. In real code where the string is being read from a file, you should be using `malloc` and `realloc` to allocate heap memory for the strings.

Comment: You are spelling Caesar incorrectly

Comment: @Abdul Hameed, did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire it did help. I am having some trouble grasping the concept of pointers and how to manipulate them. I am very grateful. Can you suggest to me a book or website you use to study C. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Main cause of segmentation fault is that you are trying to access the uninitialised memory location.

The string `encryptlis` was not initialised.

The return type of the function `ceaserEncrypt` is not correct.

Also, the conventions to pass string as parameter to the functions should be followed: The accepted convention of passing C-strings to functions is to use a pointer.

Have a look at the following working implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* ceaserEncrypt(char* string,int key);


int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    char str[100000] = "Hi there I am fine";
    int key = 20;
    char val[100000];

    strcpy(val,ceaserEncrypt(str,key));

    printf("%s",val);

    return 0;
}

char* ceaserEncrypt(char* string,int key)
{

    int len = strlen(string);
    char* encryptlis = (char*)(malloc((len+1) * sizeof(char)));


    if(key < 1 || key > 26)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Key provided is invalid");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(string[i] == ' '){
            encryptlis[i] = ' ';
            continue;
        }

        int charcode = string[i] + key;
        if(charcode > 122)
        {
            encryptlis[i] = (char) (charcode - 25);
        }
        else{
            encryptlis[i] = (char) charcode;
        }
    }
    encryptlis[len] = '\0';

    return encryptlis;
}
```